# Cropping an 8-bit bitmap by its palette information

Tags: c++, image, colors, color-palette

I'm currently using C++ to read my 8-bit bitmap and save off its pixel data and colour table. I currently have my colour table stored in an array:

```
RGBQUAD* colours;
```

I was wondering how I would go about finding the nearest unique pixel colour in all directions and cropping the bitmap to that pixel. I'm using C++ without any external libraries.

Comment: I've been advised that converting to greyscale then using an edge detection algorithm would be the best way to achieve this. Could any one give their thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend *using* readily available libraries, like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org), instead of trying to re-implement *that* particular wheel.

There's only two reasons why you would implement something already implemented that well elsewhere: 1) Homework, or 2) you think you can actually do significantly better than existing code.

It cannot be 1) because there is no "homework" tag, and it cannot be 2) because you wouldn't have to ask, then...

Comment: @Aequitas: ...but unless you tell people why you insist on reinventing the wheel, people will continue telling you, "use a wheel". ;-)

Comment: I'd simply like to learn as much as I can about lower level image manipulation without the use of libraries. In future, I will most certainly utilise a library, but first I'd like to do something myself to learn how they achieve something.

Comment: @Aequitas: Then do feel free to tag it as `[homework]`; that tag also covers self-study.

Answer (score 0):

"nearest unique pixel colour" means nearest in color space? In absolute terms (R/G/B) or human sense? So, given `#0002FE` wou may find `#0000FF` in your color table?

The "standard" simple C++ method is `std::min_element()`, which takes a range and a predicate. In your case, that range is your color table and the predicate is the close-ness to the color you want. E.g. `[targetColor](RGBQUAD tableEntry) { return abs(RGBdiff(tableEntry, targetColor)); }`

Comment: @Aequitas: That's a lot harder. Googling "color difference perception" will show you that this is a subject of ongoing research. A simple approach would be to implement `RGBdiff` with a [CIELAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB) transformation of both colors, followed by a simple difference in `Lab` space.